# Equivariant Riemann-Roch on DM stacks?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, equivariant, grothendieck-riemann-roch

Does an equivariant version of (Toen)-Riemann-Roch theorem hold say over a smooth Deligne-Mumford stack $X$ over the complex numbers?

Any  references that state this explicitely?

Are there formulas for the equivariant Chern character and Todd genus? 
(as for the Chern character, I am content with the case of a coherent sheaf supported at a point and with $X$ of dimension $2$)

Comment: What are you asking, precisely?  Where are the Chern character and Todd class supposed to take values?  The Riemann-Roch formula is usually only defined up to $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients.  If you are using $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients, the Chow groups of the stack agree with the Chow groups of its coarse moduli space.  Thus, some of the applications of Riemann-Roch for the stack follow from the corresponding statements for the coarse moduli space.

Comment: Have you had a look at Edidin's paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.4742.pdf ?

Comment: You can also consider e-mailing A. Krishna http://www.tifr.res.in/People_Finder/compcode.php?param1=39 I think he's working on generalizing work of Edidin; see his abstract here https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~alperj/kioloa-abstracts.html#Krishna

Comment: @Jason Starr : the point of Toen's construction is precisely to use a cohomology theory such that the cohomology of the stack does not coincide rationally with the cohomology of its moduli space (Toen uses, morally, "ordinary" cohomology of the inertia stack). For instance, the cohomology ring of $BG$ is (morally at least) the rational character ring of $G$, and not $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: But generally I agree  with Jason that the question needs to be reformulated more precisely. Do you start with a Deligne-Mumford stack with a group action, or is the equivariant part encoded in the fact that you consider a quotient DM stack ?

Comment: @Niels.  I do know about Riemann-Roch for stacks.  Nonetheless, for many applications, e.g., computing (virtual) canonical divisor classes of moduli spaces of various types, it suffices to work with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients and with Riemann-Roch on the coarse moduli space.  That does not suffice for all applications, but it does suffice for many applications.

Comment: I have an action of a torus on an orbifold surface $X$, and I want to compute the induced weights on the $Ext^1$ of two invariant sheaves  (assuming I know those on the $Ext^0$ and on the $Ext^2$). It would be perhaps useful to have (if it exists) a formula like $Ext^0(E,F)-Ext^1(E,F)+Ext^2(E,F)=\int_X  ch^{\vee}(E)ch(F)Td(X)$. The equality is supposed to hold in the representation ring of the torus, or in some other setting that can help computing the LHS..

Comment: This paper of mine spells it out in Appendix A and has a few examples: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.4205   The results is due to Toen: The ́ore`mes de Riemann-Roch pour les champs de Deligne-Mumford. K-Theory, 18(1):33–76, 1999. And is also spelled out in  Hsian-Hua Tseng. Orbifold quantum Riemann-Roch, Lefschetz and Serre. Geom. Topol., 14(1):1–81, 2010.